# Interacting with github API through casablanca library

Tags: c++, github, casablanca

I'm building Git client in MFC Framework, and I am using casablanca library in order to make connections with github server and make an usage of its API. In tutorial for Github one example shows how to send a request to github server with user name and password attached for the purposes of authentication:
https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

```
curl -i https://api.github.com -u valid_username:valid_password
```

Now, I've tried and tried to achieve the same effect with casablanca from Microsoft but I simply cannot get the syntax right:

```
http_client client(U("https://api.github.com/users/myuser"));
uri_builder builder(U("- u myuser:mypass"));
pplx::task<http_response> requestTask = client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());
```

After calling this I'm getting exception thrown from casablanca saying that the uri is not valid.
Any idea how to properly construct request in casablanca so I can send it to github server?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the example on the GitHub page, `-u username:password` is an option to curl:

```
-u/--user <user:password> 

    Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.
```

You can perform basic authentication with the C++ REST SDK using [`http_client_config::set_credentials()`](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client__config.html#a1b2880805c01e6e05fce6b6234b41eaa).

(Also, see the related question: [Set Basic HTTP Authentication in Casablanca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371659/set-basic-http-authentication-in-casablanca))